# How to connect to an Azure SQL database with managed identity using a console app running during in a deployment pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database

I am trying to go passwordless for connecting to an Azure SQL database, using managed identities. Connecting my .NET Core website went smooth, but now I'm trying to do the same with a console app that runs during deployment, in an Azure DevOps pipeline, whose job is to run migrations and data seeds.

At the moment, my idea is to try to connect to the database using the account created by my Devops Service Connection. To access that account from my console app, I wanted to user an Azure Powershell task to run the app, and log in on the server using [Active Directory Default authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication) (which looks like a good choice for this scenario).

What I did was:

- Create the service connection (an AzureRM service connection, configured with Workload Identity federation (automatic))
- In a classic release pipeline, add a Azure Powershell task, that runs with the service connections identity, and executes the console application
- Create the database, add a login for the account created by the service connection, and give it `datareader`, `datawriter`, and `ddladmin` roles. Open the firewall to allow access from other Azure resources.
- In the console app, connect to Azure SQL using this connection string: `Data Source=tcp:redacted.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=redacteddb; Authentication=Active Directory Default; Encrypt=True;`

But that does not work. Using the process I described here, the console app crashes with the following error message:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=314; handshake=165; [Login] initialization=2; authentication=57; [Post-Login] complete=14003;
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is there another way to do that task ?

---

Edit : Added more context information for reference:

The console app's source code

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Connection string: '{connString}'");

Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");

try
{
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Connected");

    Console.WriteLine("Creating a table...");

    string query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Hello";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    query = "CREATE TABLE Hello";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        int actionCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine($"{actionCount} affected rows");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done without errors");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

The deployment pipeline looks like this

[image]

And finaly, the output of the powershell task as of today

```
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4142211Z ##[section]Starting: Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4311735Z ==============================================================================
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4312081Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4312267Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4312636Z Version      : 5.230.0
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4312752Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4312942Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
2023-11-15T08:24:36.4313249Z ==============================================================================
2023-11-15T08:24:38.1855588Z Generating script.
2023-11-15T08:24:38.2747050Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-11-15T08:24:38.3054027Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\a663ac37-9de0-4429-9678-aff5ce3ef8e6.ps1'"
2023-11-15T08:24:40.2425157Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2023-11-15T08:24:48.8484630Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_9.3.0\Az.Accounts\2.13.1\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2023-11-15T08:24:53.0323351Z WARNING: Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the 
2023-11-15T08:24:53.0340865Z same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can
2023-11-15T08:24:53.0347471Z  use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure 
2023-11-15T08:24:53.0360272Z Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found 
2023-11-15T08:24:53.0363091Z here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
2023-11-15T08:25:19.9532103Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2023-11-15T08:25:20.6450837Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2023-11-15T08:25:20.6938006Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount System.Collections.Hashtable
2023-11-15T08:25:23.7761139Z 
2023-11-15T08:25:23.8085637Z VERBOSE: Command [Connect-AzAccount] succeeded.
2023-11-15T08:25:23.8137560Z ##[command]Set-AzContext System.Collections.Hashtable
2023-11-15T08:25:24.0568462Z VERBOSE: Command [Set-AzContext] succeeded.
2023-11-15T08:25:27.7078802Z Connection string: 'Data Source=tcp:redacted.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=redacteddb; Authentication=Active Directory Default; Encrypt=True;'
2023-11-15T08:25:27.7091314Z Connexion...
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5334476Z ##[error]Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=254; handshake=172; [Login] initialization=3; authentication=17; [Post-Login] complete=14019; 
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at DbCheckService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\DbDeploy\DbCheckService.cs:line 37
ClientConnectionId:[redacted]
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5382166Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5399882Z       Application is shutting down...
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5401124Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5402216Z       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5403087Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5407826Z       Hosting environment: Production
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5420762Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5426218Z       Content root path: D:\a\r1\a\dbdeploy\bin
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5439858Z Account                              SubscriptionName TenantId                             Environment
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5446942Z -------                              ---------------- --------                             -----------
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5462367Z *** [redacted]    [redacted] AzureCloud 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5463374Z 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5476230Z Name               : [redacted] ([redacted]) - [redacted] - 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5482252Z                      ***
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5495682Z Account            : ***
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5502212Z Environment        : AzureCloud
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5515078Z Subscription       : [redacted]
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5521024Z Tenant             : [redacted]
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5528995Z TokenCache         : 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5538222Z VersionProfile     : 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5546931Z ExtendedProperties : {}
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5552281Z 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5557895Z 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.5563558Z 
2023-11-15T08:25:44.8553919Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2023-11-15T08:25:45.2851397Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript
```

Comment: Could you please provide the sample code?

Comment: @Bhavani done in initial post

Comment: Are you sure you are authenticating against MSI? To `Create the service connection (an AzureRM service connection, configured with Workload Identity federation (automatic))` will create a **new** app registration(service principal) in your AAD first and then use the SP to authenticate access to Azure rather than against a user assigned managed identity.

Comment: @AlvinZhao I think so yes. I have checked the user created by the service connection (the "Managed Service Principal"), and added that user to my SQL database using `CREATE USER [service_principal_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`

Comment: May I ask if there is any misunderstanding on `Managed Identity` in the title? It is a **resource** under your subscription. If you created ARM service connection in Azure DevOps and could view the service principal in your AAD with the link `manage service principal`, please note that it will redirect you to **App registration** in your AAD rather than a **managed identity** in your subscription.

Anyway, have you tried to run the command `dotnet doDeploy.dll` locally after `Connect-AzAccount` against this service principal? If it works locally, is it running in an non-interactive mode?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I did incorrectly assume that the app registration was the managed identity. That being said, the managed identity (which would be the Enterprise Application if I understand things correctly ?) has the exact same name as the app registration, so I'm assuming the account name I put in Azure is still correct ? I did try to run the app locally using Azure PS, which worked as expected. `Connect-AzAccount` showed me a login interface, and the console app picked up my user and connected successfully without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Azure active directory interactive is more secure than active directory default.  So, you can use below connection sting:

```
Server=tcp:<serverNmae>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<ADId>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=\"Active Directory Interactive\";
```

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

string connectionString = "Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<ADId>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=\"Active Directory Interactive\";";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string query = "SELECT * FROM <tableName>";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int studentId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                string Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                Console.WriteLine($"StudentID: {studentId}, Name: {Name}");
                     
                }
        }
    }

}
```

It will open browser for authentication for the first time. after that it will connect automatically after connecting. The database is connected successfully as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I'm really confused by this answer. How could this possibly work in a CI pipeline scenario, since there will be no user on the deployment VM to interact with the authentication ? Also, I want to use a service account for deployments, not a user account...

Comment: If there is no user on the deployment VM to interact with the authentication then create [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/create-service-principal-azure) and try to [authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=sqldatabase%2Csystemassigned%2Cnetfx%2Cwindowsclient) with it.

Comment: I did this, but can't get it working, precisely for the reasons explained in my initial question...

Comment: If `It will open browser for authentication for the first time`, it is not supported in Azure pipelines, because pipeline doesn't support interactive sessions.

Comment: could you please check [this](https://blog.bredvid.no/handling-azure-managed-identity-access-to-azure-sql-in-an-azure-devops-pipeline-1e74e1beb10b) once?